# Open an existing document (MXD) inside ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, mxd

I try to open a specific MXD inside a running ArcMap-Application, but I always get "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" and ArcMap crashes.
I have an Add-In-toolbar with a button, which opens a form (modal). Inside the form I show a combobox with available MXDs. In the OK-Buttons Click event I want to open the chosen MXD (below the mxd is a constant for test):

```
    Dim mxd As String = "D:\temp4\mytest.mxd"
    Dim pApp As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IApplication = My.ArcMap.Application

    Dim pMapDoc As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMapDocument = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.MapDocumentClass
    If pMapDoc.IsMapDocument(mxd) Then
        pApp.OpenDocument(mxd)
        'pApp.OpenDocument()
    End If
```

Also if I try to open it without the optional argument (mxd), ArcMap crashes with the same error. But it should open the dialog to choose a MXD.
What's wrong, who can help ?